# Increment "1" to a formatted number with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm displaying a number field formatted with PHP in my HTML.

```
$totalShares = get_field('share_count');
$totalFormat = number_format( $totalShares, 0, '.', ',' );

echo 'Shared: <span class="totalShares">'.$totalFormat.'</span> times';
```

With jQuery and Ajax I add 1 by clicking a button but it transforms, for example, 8,500 (8500) to 9 in the HTML. If I refresh, I have 8,501.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    
    $('.social-icon').on('click', function() {
        
        $.ajax({
            url: bloginfo.site_url + '/wp-json/functions/shares/' + bloginfo.post_id.ID,
            type: 'post',
            success: function() {
                console.log('works!');
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('failed!');
            }
        });
        
        // Change the like number in the HTML to add 1
        var updated_shares = parseInt($('.totalShares').html()) + 1;
        
        $('.totalShares').html(updated_shares);
                
    });
    
});
```

How to correct this part `var updated_likes = parseInt($('.share_count').html()) + 1;` ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you think `success: function() {` could be used for?  Remove the example `console.log('works!');` and place there your code.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `.html()` and `.text()`

Comment: A quick and dirty solution would be to use something like`parseInt($('.share_count').html().replace(/[^\d]/g,'')) + 1` to get rid of any formatting char (NB, the result is not formatted either), but a much nicer solution would be to have the update call return the new (formatted) value. This has the extra benefit of getting the latest value if another user updated too

Comment: Thank you both I added toLocaleString ('en-US') in addition for the formatting. `var updated_shares = parseInt($('.share_count').text().replace(/[^\d]/g,'')) + 1;` and `$('.share_count').text(updated_shares.toLocaleString('en-US'));`